# Ошибка при преобразовании значений textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, int

У меня на форме есть textBox1 и textBox2, в которых выводится информация о выбранном предмете. Мне нужно, чтобы на этой же форме в textBox3 выводился результат вычислений.

Пишу следующий код:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
int b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
int c = (a * b) / 100;
textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(с);
```

Но при запуске мне выдает следующую ошибку: `System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."` уже на первой же строке с объявлением переменной a.

Как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Ну надо проверять - может там пробелы, может переводы строки есть

Comment: В этих textbox1-2 отображаются именно цифры, а не текст. Но чтобы суметь вычислить новый результат,  пытаюсь преобразовать из string в int

Comment: Если вам пишет "Имеет неверный формат", то там явно не только цифры и тут я верю больше ошибке, чем вам. Поставьте точку остановки на одну из строк с конвертацией и смотрите что в `textBox1.Text`. Да и вообще, уберите этот ужасный `Convert` класс, он стар как мир! Используйте `int.TryParse()` или `int.Parse()`.

Comment: Для начала — в вашем коде в 3-й строке переменная `c` — латинская (0x61), а в 4-й — кириллическая (0x441). А еще непонятно, откуда взят этот кусок кода. Если он выполняется еще до начала ввода чисел в текстбоксы, то вышеуказанная ошибка гарантирована.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
int b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
float c = (a * b) / 100;
textBox3.Text = c.ToString();
```

Так же можно убрать пробелы исключить всё, что не цифра и тд.
    YourString.Replace(" ", "");
Замена пробела на пустой символ.